Odoo snippet not visible in Website Builder after module installation
I'm developing a custom module for Odoo 16 that adds a BMI calculator snippet to the Website Builder. However, after installing the module, the snippet does not appear in the blocks section of the page editor.
Here’s what I have done so far:

I added my snippet in a snippet_templates.xml file.
I included the CSS and JS files in assets.xml file.
My __manifest__.py contains the paths to the views and assets.
The module installs correctly, but the snippet does not show up in the snippets section.

and here's what I’ve tried:

I cleared Odoo’s cache.
I verified that the module is installed correctly.
I tried different methods to inject the snippet into the website.snippets template.

What I expect: My snippet to appear in the snippet section of Odoo’s page editor, but it’s not visible.
